# Generating Random Number in Solidity is pending

Tags: solidity, random

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

    uint256 private RandNonce = 0;
    function RandomNumber() public returns(uint256){
        uint256 rand = uint(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(block.timestamp,msg.sender,RandNonce))) % 100; 
        RandNonce++;
        return rand;
    }
```

I made this function in Remix and deployed well. But this function not working
errorCode : transact to SimpleCoin.RandomNumber pending ...

what's wrong this function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might be that you have to wrap the function and the variable in a `contract`, so:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

    contract Random {
        uint256 private RandNonce = 0;

        function randomNumber() public returns(uint256){
            uint256 rand = uint(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(block.timestamp,msg.sender,RandNonce))) % 100; 
            RandNonce++;
            return rand;
        }
  }
```

The function itself looks like it should be callable as is.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. But I wrapped in a contract, just i left out in question. 
And I deployed again and execute function, it works... I modified nothing. Anyway Thanks for your effort:)